How do you pack a large file into a .tar?
How do you pack a large file into a Tar?
If you use this code, then a lot of RAM is used.
byte[] buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(1024 * 1024);
string item = @"R:\Bigfile.dat";
using (FileStream _writestream = File.Create(@"R:\test.tar")
using (TarWriter tarwriter = new(_writestream, TarEntryFormat.Pax, leaveOpen: false))
using (FileStream srcFile = new(item, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string fileName = item.Remove(0, mainDir.Length + 1).Replace('\\', '/');
    PaxTarEntry te = new(TarEntryType.RegularFile, fileName)
    {
        DataStream = new MemoryStream()
    };
    
    int currentBlockSize = 0;
    while ((currentBlockSize = srcFile.Read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        te.DataStream.Write(buffer.AsSpan(0, currentBlockSize));
    }
    te.DataStream.Position = 0;
    tarwriter.WriteEntry(te);
}
ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);

If you use this code, it will use a lot of memory. Yes, probably because it will be written to MemoryStream(). But what are the better options if need to write a VERY large file? I want to write to a .tar file instead of RAM, and I want can control the size of each iteration of the write cycle through the buffer size.

What is _writestream here? If you could provide a [mcve] it would be easier to help you. (And you're explicitly creating a MemoryStream that you're writing to, so it's not particularly surprising that it takes a lot of memory, IMO...)

@JonSkeet I fixed it. But I don't know where to write if not to MemoryStream?

Can you definitely not just use srcFile as the DataStream? (That's what I'd have expected to do - I'd also just use File.OpenRead rather than explicitly calling the FileStream constructor, just for simplicity...)

It's not clear what's meant by "I want can control the size of each iteration of the write cycle through the buffer size" - iteration of what? (In my proposed solution, you wouldn't have anything to iterate over...)

I think you just don't need to do the copying from the input stream in memory at all. Here's a short but complete program which builds a tar file from each command line argument:
using System.Formats.Tar;

using var output = File.Create("output.tar");
using var tarWriter = new TarWriter(output, TarEntryFormat.Pax);

foreach (var arg in args)
{
    using var input = File.OpenRead(arg);
    var entry = new PaxTarEntry(TarEntryType.RegularFile, arg)
    {
        DataStream = input
    };
    tarWriter.WriteEntry(entry);
}

I've just used that code to create a 20GB tar file (from several 1-3GB files), and Task Manager only showed it using 3.6MB...

@JonSkeet Why not use the async versions? await using var output await using var tarWriter await using var input = File.OpenRead await tarWriter.WriteEntryAsync

@Charlieface: Yes, you could absolutely do that. But given that the original code isn't async, and there's no indication of a requirement to make it async, it felt like it would be wrong to unilaterally do that.

using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

public void PackLargeFileIntoTar(string sourceFilePath, string tarFilePath)
{
    using (FileStream tarFileStream = new FileStream(tarFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using (TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.Create())
    {
        tarArchive.WriteTo(tarFileStream, TarEntryFormat.Pax, leaveOpen: false);

        using (FileStream srcFile = new FileStream(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath);
            var entry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(sourceFilePath);
            tarArchive.AddEntry(fileName, srcFile);
        }
    }
}


Where does TarArchive come from? The built in Tar implementation is TarFile as far as I know.

I've updated the question. Your answer doesn't seem to fit. It doesn't use a buffer, and you're also using a .net implementation of .tar support that isn't built into .net

@Raf-9600: "and you're also using a .net implementation of .tar support that isn't built into .net" - your question didn't stipulate that as a requirement. I agree the answer could be clearer, but if you're going to reject any answer that uses a third party library, that should definitely be in the question.

@Raf-9600: It's also not clear what you mean by "It doesn't use a buffer" - what precise behavior do you require that is related to buffering? (What do you mean in the question by "I want can control the size of each iteration of the write cycle through the buffer size"?

@JonSkeet I would like to be able to display the progress of a .tar pack, usually you have to use a buffer to do this. But I don't know how to do it in this case.

@Raf-9600: Again, no mention of that in the question. You could create a stream wrapper which counts bytes read etc, potentially - but it would be relatively fiddly. I would weigh up how much you really want that compared with how much hassle it would be.
